# How to effectively create "needed" boilerplate?

Tags: design

This problem arises in the context of a web application.

When we send a request from front-end to back-end, we must map the data, e.g. in post request:
`{ something : this.something }`

When we receive it, we must map it to a .new() method like `some_class.new(something = input['something'])`

Also, someone must make the `.new(something): some_class.something = something`

This needs to work across multiple languages. So JS is needed for front-end, python or go is needed for back-end, and finally a DB wrapper such as ORM is needed for database management.

Is this unavoidable? Is the best practice to build a string generator that takes a representation in a known format and outputs the various (slightly different) mappings as shown above?

Comment: You can avoid almost all boilerplate if desired, but it's a design decision. For example, only include your data model in the front end and have the back-end just pass it to a document database such as mongoDB. But many people prefer to include the model in the back-end as well (or a variation of it) because it allows for validation or domain separation.

Answer (score 2):

There are various tools that will help you with boilerplate from code snippets to templating languages.

But in my experience unless you have a whole lot to do at once, which might be the case with say converting from one language to another, it's easiest simply to copy paste and edit.

The problem with code generation is that like any genericism it can fail with edge cases. You spend longer writing the perfect boiler plate code generator that it would take simply to type the code.

If you have the entire input layed out for you then you can see all the edge cases up front. If you are doing it as you go then you are constantly adding and retesting.

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but to be fair, very often there exists a compromise between the "perfect boiler plate code generator", and writing all code manually: a code generator which creates "standard" boilerplate but still lets one add the "edge cases" manually.

Comment: Hmm maybe, EF database first for example is near perfect code generation, but people still prefer code first.

Comment: Xamarin is pretty much cross platform, but I would still recommend writing two/three native apps vs one xamarin app